# Use sizeof with incomplete type inside std::conditional

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, type-traits, incomplete-type

Here is a minimal example:

```
struct incomplete_type;

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>,
        std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) < sizeof(void*), int, float>,
        double>;
};
```

`foo<incomplete_type> f;` will cause error because it will do sizeof with type, even though `incomplete_type` is not a arithmetic type(iow, it will not go into sizeof branch logically). [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/c0iZDoHrIEEud9Rv)

So, I want to **defer** `sizeof`:

#### first attempt(fail)

```
template<typename T>
auto
foo_aux()
{
    if(sizeof(T) < sizeof(T*))
        return 0;
    else
        return 0.0f;
}
```

`conditional_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, decltype(foo_aux<T>()), double>` still trigger the same error.

#### second attempt(fail)

```
template<typename T, bool>
struct foo_aux_aux
{
    using type = float;
};
template<typename T>
struct foo_aux_aux<T, true>
{
    using type = int;
};

template<typename T, bool = false>
struct foo_aux : foo_aux_aux<T, sizeof(T) < sizeof(void*)>
{};
```

`conditional_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, typename foo_aux<T>::type, double>` still trigger the same error.

#### third attempt(success)

```
template<typename T, bool comp>
struct foo_aux_aux
{
    using type = float;
};
template<typename T>
struct foo_aux_aux<T, true>
{
    using type = int;
};

template<typename T, bool isArithmeticType>
struct foo_aux
{
    using type = double;
};

template<typename T>
struct foo_aux<T, true>
{
    using type = typename foo_aux_aux<T, sizeof(T) < sizeof(void*)>::type;
};
```

[Yes, it works as expected](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uUxzQeKFlVtlStL7), but its really tedious and ugly.

Do you have an elegant way here?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++17, you can use `if constexpr` to do type computation. Just wrap the type into a dummy container and use value computation, then retrieve the type via `decltype`.

`struct foo` could be implemented like:

```
template<class T>
struct type_ {
    using type = T;
};

template<class T>
struct foo {
    auto constexpr static type_impl() {
        if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<T>{}) {
            if constexpr (sizeof(T) < sizeof(void*)) {
                return type_<int>{};
            } else {
                return type_<float>{};
            }
        } else {
            return type_<double>{};
        }
    }

    using type = typename decltype(type_impl())::type;
};

static_assert(std::is_same<foo<incomplete_type>::type, double>{});
```

Comment: Cool! I decide to rewrite some of my own traits with `if constexpr`

Answer (score 5):

Your second attempt works if you wrap `double` in `type_identity` (which is [a standard utility](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) in C++20) and move `::type` after `std::conditional_t<...>`:

```
template<typename T, bool>
struct foo_aux_aux
{
    using type = float;
};
template<typename T>
struct foo_aux_aux<T, true>
{
    using type = int;
};

template<typename T, bool = false>
struct foo_aux : foo_aux_aux<T, sizeof(T) < sizeof(void*)>
{};

template<typename T>
struct type_identity { using type = T; };

typename std::conditional_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, foo_aux<T>, type_identity<double>>::type
```

Comment: I like that you've simply adapted the OP's code to work instead of proposing a new solution.

Comment: Thanks, man! I use type_identity heavily in my own codes, but this is the first time to its power expect for replacing `using type =`

Comment: `foo_aux_aux` is just a special case of `conditional`.

Answer (score 4):

Not a great improvement, I suppose, but you can rewrite your third (working) attempt in a little less ugly (IMHO) way using `decltype()` and declaring (only) some functions.

I mean something as

```
struct incomplete_type;

constexpr float baz (std::false_type);
constexpr int baz (std::true_type);

template <typename>
constexpr double bar (std::false_type);

template <typename T>
constexpr auto bar (std::true_type)
 -> decltype(baz<std::bool_constant<(sizeof(T) < sizeof(void*))>{});

template<typename T>
struct foo
 { using type = decltype( bar<T>(std::is_arithmetic<T>{}) ); };
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use SFINAE:

```
template <class T1, class T2, class = int (*)[sizeof(T1) < sizeof(T2)]>
constexpr bool DeferSizeof(int) {
  return true;
}
template <class, class>
constexpr bool DeferSizeof(...) {
  return false;
}

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>,
        std::conditional_t<DeferSizeof<T, void *>(0), int, float>,
        double>;
};
```

Comment: I tried void_t before posting this question, but failed somehow. Your SFINAE solution inspires me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With [detection idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) from TS Library Fundamentals v2:

```
template <typename T>
using size_of = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof(T)>;

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_arithmetic_v<T>,
        std::conditional_t<
            std::experimental::detected_or_t<
                std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>, size_of, T
            >{} < sizeof(void*),
            int, float>,
        double>;
};
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lb7kADHnzRnuObZQ)

Comment: I'm a big fan of Walter E. Brown, thanks for this solution!

Comment: detection idiom is not C++20.

Comment: @T.C. are there plans to integrate it into the standard library?

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of, and not likely with concepts already merged.